# How to use AIML to find category out of topic?

Tags: aiml

I have been using AIML to make chatbot. I want search category out of topic after set data in topic. But, i don't have idea for that

1. set day
2. set class
3. search category out of topic use day and class

How could I do that?

Thanks in advance.

```
<category>
        <pattern>SCHEDULE</pattern>
        <template>
            <think><set name="topic">SCHEDULE</set></think>
            day ?</template>
    </category>
    
    <topic name="SCHEDULE">
        <category>
            <pattern><set>setdays</set></pattern>
            <template>
                <think><set name="day"><star/></set></think>
                <condition name="day">
                    <li value="Monday"><set name="day"><star/></set> for class?</li>
                    <li value="Tuesday"><set name="day"><star/></set> for class?</li>
                    <li value="Wednesday"><set name="day"><star/></set> for class?</li>
                    <li value="Thursday"><set name="day"><star/></set> for class?</li>
                    <li value="Friday"><set name="day"><star/></set> for class?</li>
                    <li value="Saturday"><set name="day"><star/></set> for class?</li>
                    <li value="Sunday"><set name="day"><star/></set> for class?</li>
                    <li>not found</li>
                </condition>
            </template>
        </category>
        
        <category>
            <pattern><set>setclass</set></pattern>
            <template>
                <think>
                    <set name="search"><get name="day"/> <set name="class"></set></set>
                    
                    After set class i want to search category out of topic
                    
                </think>
            </template>
        </category>
        
    </topic>
```

Answer (score 1):

To search out of topic, reset your topic name to something that doesn't exist. Also you need `<star/>` instead of `<set name="class"></set>` in your template.

```
    <category>
        <pattern><set>setclass</set></pattern>
        <template>
            <think>
                <set name="search"><get name="day"/> <star/></set>
                <set name="topic">none</set>
            </think>
        </template>
    </category>
```

Comment: i've try change ``<set name="class"></set>`` to <star/> and set topic "none". I see search variable "MONDAY 01" and topic "none" look good. But, i don't get any answer

Comment: That's right because the template is surrounded by think tags. All it does is set a predicate called "search" and a topic. What are you wanting it to do?

Comment: i just set day and class in schedule topic. After set class i want get answer from other AIML file.

example: 
1. scheduletopic.AIML (topic for set parameter)
2. schedulelist.AIML (answer here)

how to do that ?

Comment: You need to use srai to call your search category <srai>SEARCHCLASSES <get name="search"/></srai>